# VB.Net War Game

Tags: vb.net

I have been working on a "WAR" card game in class. I seem to have most of it setup correctly, however, I am having some issues dealing 2 new cards to the image boxes when clicking the deal button.

The exact things I need the draw button to accomplish is 
***When the draw button is pressed, the first two cards from the shuffled deck
should show up, one on the left and one on the right side. The middle card will be the
“Left win”, “Right Win”, or “Tie” image and is correctly indicate who won (with the higher
card). Furthermore, the winner’s score should increase by 1 point.***

I will include a screenshot of my form to give you an idea of what I am working with and where I should go with the deal button. My guess is when I click the deal button a second time it is resetting the values back to 0 and 26 respectively.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwuO5.png)

```
  Public Class Form1


    'WAR

    Dim cardarray(52) As Image
    Dim valuearray(52) As Integer
    Dim cardval1, cardval2 As Integer
    Dim card1, card2 As Integer
    Dim P1, P2 As Integer


    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


        pct1.Image = My.Resources.back
        pct2.Image = My.Resources.back
        pct3.Image = My.Resources.back

        'Needed to generate a random number/card
        Randomize()

        'create 52 card element array
        CardArray(0) = My.Resources.twoc
        CardArray(1) = My.Resources.twod
        CardArray(2) = My.Resources.twoh
        CardArray(3) = My.Resources.twos
        CardArray(4) = My.Resources.threec
        CardArray(5) = My.Resources.threed
        CardArray(6) = My.Resources.threeh
        CardArray(7) = My.Resources.threes
        CardArray(8) = My.Resources.fourc
        CardArray(9) = My.Resources.fourd
        CardArray(10) = My.Resources.fourh
        CardArray(11) = My.Resources.fours
        CardArray(12) = My.Resources.fivec
        CardArray(13) = My.Resources.fived
        CardArray(14) = My.Resources.fiveh
        CardArray(15) = My.Resources.fives
        CardArray(16) = My.Resources.sixc
        CardArray(17) = My.Resources.sixd
        CardArray(18) = My.Resources.sixh
        CardArray(19) = My.Resources.sixs
        CardArray(20) = My.Resources.sevenc
        CardArray(21) = My.Resources.sevend
        CardArray(22) = My.Resources.sevenh
        CardArray(23) = My.Resources.sevens
        CardArray(24) = My.Resources.eightc
        CardArray(25) = My.Resources.eightd
        CardArray(26) = My.Resources.eighth
        CardArray(27) = My.Resources.eights
        CardArray(28) = My.Resources.ninec
        CardArray(29) = My.Resources.nined
        CardArray(30) = My.Resources.nineh
        CardArray(31) = My.Resources.nines
        CardArray(32) = My.Resources.tenc
        CardArray(33) = My.Resources.tend
        CardArray(34) = My.Resources.tenh
        CardArray(35) = My.Resources.tens
        CardArray(36) = My.Resources.jackc
        CardArray(37) = My.Resources.jackd
        CardArray(38) = My.Resources.jackh
        CardArray(39) = My.Resources.jacks
        CardArray(40) = My.Resources.queenc
        CardArray(41) = My.Resources.queend
        CardArray(42) = My.Resources.queenh
        CardArray(43) = My.Resources.queens
        CardArray(44) = My.Resources.kingc
        CardArray(45) = My.Resources.kingd
        CardArray(46) = My.Resources.kingh
        CardArray(47) = My.Resources.kings
        CardArray(48) = My.Resources.acec
        CardArray(49) = My.Resources.aced
        CardArray(50) = My.Resources.aceh
        CardArray(51) = My.Resources.aces

        '52 integer value array

        valueArray(0) = 1
        valueArray(1) = 1
        valueArray(2) = 1
        valueArray(3) = 1
        valueArray(4) = 2
        valueArray(5) = 2
        valueArray(6) = 2
        valueArray(7) = 2
        valueArray(8) = 3
        valueArray(9) = 3
        valueArray(10) = 3
        valueArray(11) = 3
        valueArray(12) = 4
        valueArray(13) = 4
        valueArray(14) = 4
        valueArray(15) = 4
        valueArray(16) = 5
        valueArray(17) = 5
        valueArray(18) = 5
        valueArray(19) = 5
        valueArray(20) = 6
        valueArray(21) = 6
        valueArray(22) = 6
        valueArray(23) = 6
        valueArray(24) = 7
        valueArray(25) = 7
        valueArray(26) = 7
        valueArray(27) = 7
        valueArray(28) = 8
        valueArray(29) = 8
        valueArray(30) = 8
        valueArray(31) = 8
        valueArray(32) = 9
        valueArray(33) = 9
        valueArray(34) = 9
        valueArray(35) = 9
        valueArray(36) = 10
        valueArray(37) = 10
        valueArray(38) = 10
        valueArray(39) = 10
        valueArray(40) = 11
        valueArray(41) = 11
        valueArray(42) = 11
        valueArray(43) = 11
        valueArray(44) = 12
        valueArray(45) = 12
        valueArray(46) = 12
        valueArray(47) = 12
        valueArray(48) = 13
        valueArray(49) = 13
        valueArray(50) = 13
        valueArray(51) = 13
    End Sub

    Public Sub shuffel()



        Dim switch As Integer
        Dim tempcard As Image
        Dim number_of_cards, tempval As Integer
        number_of_cards = 52
        'Go through the deck one card at a time:
        For i = 0 To number_of_cards - 1
            'Get a random card number from the deck
            switch = Int(Rnd() * number_of_cards)
            'Switch the current card’s value with the random card’s value
            tempval = valuearray(i)
            valuearray(i) = valuearray(switch)
            valuearray(switch) = tempval
            'Switch the current card’s image with the random card’s image
            tempcard = cardarray(i)
            cardarray(i) = cardarray(switch)
            cardarray(switch) = tempcard
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnClear.Click


        'shuffle deck and set scores to 0
        Call shuffel()

        txtP1.Text = 0
        txtP2.Text = 0


    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtP2.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnShuffle_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShuffle.Click

        'shuffle deck and change card backs
        Call shuffel()

        pct1.Image = My.Resources.back
        pct2.Image = My.Resources.back
        pct3.Image = My.Resources.back


    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDraw_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDraw.Click

        'set interger values for starting points
        cardval1 = 0
        cardval2 = 26

        'load those starting points into image boxes
        pct1.Image = cardarray(cardval1)
        pct3.Image = cardarray(cardval2)

        'increase card values by 1
        cardval1 = (cardval1 + 1)
        cardval2 = (cardval2 + 1)
    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: You said, "My guess is when I click the deal button a second time it is resetting the values back to 0 and 26 respectively."  Have you tried debugging?  That should be your first step in troubleshooting: Set a breakpoint in the area where you think it isn't behaving as you expect, hit F5 to run in the debugger, and see what ensues.  Revise your target area based on what you find (maybe the problem occurs earlier or later than you expect).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think that you should move the part in btnDraw_Click where you are setting the starting points to btnShuffle_CLick and this would get what you are after?